# Electric 220 stove wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing my electric slide in range with a stand alone model.  The original was hard wired and the new is with a cord.  There are 3 wires and a bare copper wire coming from the wall.  What should I do with the copper wire.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a [NEMA 14-50 outlet](http://www.menards.com/main/electrical/wiring-devices/outlets/50a-surface-range-outlet/p-1401412-c-9526.htm) for your new stove.  Connect the black wire to L1, the red wire to L2, the white wire to N, and the copper wire to G, then plug your stove in.

Comment: Thanks. Someone said I could just cap that wire off. As if it were an extra ground and not needed?

Comment: @Theresa You should **not** just cap the bare grounding wire off.

Comment: @Theresa -- seconding Tester101 on this -- whoever gave you this advice was *very* misinformed -- if your range has a NEMA 10 (3 prong) plug on it, **change the range cord out for a 4-prong one!**